# How to know number of items added to cart in WordPress shopping cart with SHOPP PLUGIN

Tags: wordpress, shopping-cart, shopp

I'm doing a shopping cart with wordpress using Shopp Plugin.

How can i know the number of items added to cart here.Any code for this.
Can any one please help me.

Answer (score 2):

I added a code to count the number of items in cart and output them.

Hope it helps!

```
<p class="cartinfo">
    <?php if (shopp('cart','hasitems')): ?>
      <?php $total_items = 0; ?>
      <?php while(shopp('cart','items')): ?>
        <?php $total_items = $total_items + 1; ?>
      <?php endwhile; ?>
    <?php echo $total_items;?> <?php if ($total_items = 1) {echo'Item';} else {echo'Items';} ?> (<?php shopp('cart','subtotal'); ?>)

    <?php else: ?>
    0 Items in Cart :(
    <?php endif; ?>
    </p>
```

Answer (score 2):

I think this does what you want?

```
<?php shopp('cart','totalitems'); ?>
```

Here are the docs on it: [Cart_Tags#totalitems](http://docs.shopplugin.net/Cart_Tags#totalitems)

UPDATED: The docs are now open to the public and updated. Here is a new link for the same function. Note the 'alternative forms' available: [shopp('cart','total-items')](https://shopplugin.net/api/cart-total-items/)

Answer (score 0):

This part has always been a little confusing in Shopp.

If you need the number of unique items in the cart you should use

```
shopp('cart','totalitems','options...');
```

(for example: 5 apples, 3 pears, 2 carrots would result in 3)

If you need the number of items in the cart you should use

```
shopp('cart','total-quantity','options...');
```

(for example: 2 apples, 3 pears, 1 carrot would result in 6)

To use the value in a variable, set options to `'return=true'`

Comment: and in a shorter version you could use $total_items = shopp('cart.get-total-quantity')